# Can a markup option be added to rotate an image?

Tags: feature-request

A never ending stream of numb-numbs post images that end up sideways. Can the site be improved to add markup to rotate such images?

Comment: Related feature request on Meta.SE: [Allow for image rotation using markup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207363/260760) and [Picture rotation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264100/260760)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am against it. If the OP cannot be bothered to at least provide an image that one can read/view without a health hazard, the question itself often is not that stellar. Leave a comment asking to rotate it; I personally also down-vote, as a question you cannot read is not helpful, but that is everyone's own choice.

Comment: I agree that the burden ought to  be on the OP. But the markup is a huge obstacle to a new user. Trying to help the user with editing the question is a pain. The image must be downloaded, rotated, saved, and then reloaded to the post. Often that also means cropping it a bit better. It would be easier for us just to be able to add some sort of rotate markup.